# grocery crud add print action to each record in list or on read page

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have a grocery crud view (table) with controller code as follows:

```
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    /*set theme and table*/
    $crud->set_table('company');

    /*column in displayed table and fields to view/add/edit */
    $crud->columns('Id','Name','Email','Address','LogoURL');
    $crud->fields('Name','Description','Email','Address','LogoURL');
    $crud->display_as('LogoURL','Logo');

    /*required field in add/edit*/
    $crud->required_fields('Name','Address');
    $crud->set_field_upload('LogoURL','images');

    $output = $crud->render();
    $crud->set_subject('Company');

    $this->load->view('admin/view/company',$output);
```

This created view as follows:

[image]

Now when I click on view (which goes to read controller, i guess), it displays as below:

[image]

Here I can see button for `Back to list`. In similar way I'd like to add `print` action in action list in table, which when clicked should redirect to page similar to above 'view page' with `Print` button on it, which should print only form displayed.

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve it? Or any other method to print each record individually from list page or from view page?

Comment: Please ask your question in http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/ someone might help you.

Comment: yup.. I added question there too.